# How to create an Inline through a chain of foreign keys in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

Supposing I have these Django models:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre')

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
```

I want to define inlines in Django Admin for a Genre instance showing all related books. How can I do it?

I tried this way:

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 0

class GenreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline]

admin.site.register(Genre, GenreAdmin)
```

that brought me the error:

```
ValueError: 'Book' has no ForeignKey to 'Genre'
```

How can I define the inline correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should put Genre on the Book, and then create a method on the Authors that will list the book's genres on it, so basically Authors genre's will be populated from Books.